# Most Productive Month

Tags: mysql, sql

Description
Write a query to find the month number (Eg: 4 corresponds to April) in which the most number of payments were made.

Table name: `payment`

Columns: `payment_date`, `payment_id`,

I tried this

```
SELECT count(payment_id) as no_of_payments, MONTH(payment_date) as payment_month 
FROM payment
group BY payment_month
group BY no_of_payments
limit 1;
```

It shows error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group BY no_of_payments
> limit 1' at line 4

Comment: So you want us to solve your homework... Why won't you try yourself first? It's for the sake of making you a better specialist

Comment: You need to group only by `payment_month`, so remove the other `GROUP BY` line. Also I don't see any reason to use `limit 1`

Comment: `GROUP BY payment_month, no_of_payments`. And probably you only need `GROUP BY payment_month`

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `group by` and `order by`.  The second `group by` should be ordering the results so you get the largest value:

```
SELECT count(payment_id) as no_of_payments, MONTH(payment_date) as payment_month 
FROM payment
GROUP BY payment_month
ORDER BY no_of_payments DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

By default, ordering is ascending, so to get the largest you need a descending sort.

In general, a month without a year is not very useful.  Sometimes, you want to combine months from across years, but that is rather rare.  Your question is ambiguous whether it wants a calendar month (i.e. in a specific year) or the month overall (say to detect seasonality), but you might want a `WHERE` clause or to aggregate by both year and month.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select month(payment_date) as mn, 
count(payment_id) as 
No_of_payments from payment 
group by mn 
order by No_of_payments desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the second `GROUP BY` in your query is a mere typo and you wanted `ORDER BY` instead.

However, the task is not very precise, because it doesn't specify what to do in a case of a tie. Usually, if there are two top months, one would not want to pick one arbitrarily, but show both.

In that case `LIMIT 1` is not at all helpful, especially, because unlike standard SQL's `FETCH` clause it doesn't have a tie clause.

The easiest way to go about this is a window function (`MAX OVER` in below query):

```
select no_of_payments, payment_month
from
(
  select
    count(*) as no_of_payments,
    max(count(*)) over () as max_no_of_payments,
    month(payment_date) as payment_month
  from payment
  group by month(payment_date) 
) months
where no_of_payments = max_no_of_payments
order by payment_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 month(pdate) as m, count(*) as c
from payment
group by pdate
order by c desc
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(payment_id) as no_of_payments, MONTH(payment_date) as payment_month 
FROM payment
group BY payment_month
Order by no_of_payments desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.mnth, cnt from (
  select MONTH(Payment_date) as mnth, count(payment_id) as cnt, 
  rank() over(order by count(payment_id) desc) as rnk from payment
  group by mnth ) p where rnk =1
```

Comment: This is a good solution, and I hadn't read it when I posted mine. I see now you had been proposing about the same solution as I have now. When writing answers, though, you should explain what your query does and what problem it solves. Don't post code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MONTH(payment_date), count(Payment_id)
from Payment
group by MONTH(payment_date)
order by count(Payment_id) DESC
limit 1;

there you go this one works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).